# "Merging" grouped rows (column-wise, picking the first non-null value, ordered by another column)

Tags: oracle-11g, group-by

I'd like to apologize in advance for the poor title, but I had a hard time trying to describe my problem.

I have a table like this:

```
+---+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+
|   | RECORD_LEVEL | RECORD_GROUP | COL_A | COL_B | COL_C |
+---+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1 |            1 | group1       | NULL  | 0     | bar1  |
| 2 |            2 | group1       | foo2  | -1    | bar2  |
| 3 |            2 | group2       | foo3  | NULL  | NULL  |
| 4 |            5 | group2       | foo4  | 5     | bar4  |
| 5 |            1 | group3       | NULL  | 1     | NULL  |
| 6 |            2 | group3       | foo6  | 1     | NULL  |
+---+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

And I need to group it by `RECORD_GROUP`, using the first non-NULL value for each column. By 'first', I imply an `ORDER BY RECORD_LEVEL ASC`. The result I'd like is something like this:

```
+---+--------------+-------+-------+-------+
|   | RECORD_GROUP | COL_A | COL_B | COL_C |
+---+--------------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1 | group1       | foo2  |     0 | bar1  |
| 2 | group2       | foo3  |     5 | bar4  |
| 3 | group3       | foo6  |     1 | NULL  |
+---+--------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I tried to reproduce this scenario in this fiddle: http://rextester.com/UMMP61375

Please, feel free to ask for more information or premises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FIRST_VALUE` analytic function for this:

```
select distinct
  record_group,
  first_value(col_a ignore nulls) over
    (partition by record_group order by record_level
      rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as col_a,
  first_value(col_b ignore nulls) over 
    (partition by record_group order by record_level
      rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as col_b,
  first_value(col_c ignore nulls) over
    (partition by record_group order by record_level
      rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as col_c
from
  tbl_record
order by
  record_group
;

RECORD_GROUP         COL_A                     COL_B COL_C              
-------------------- -------------------- ---------- --------------------
group1               foo2                          0 bar1                
group2               foo3                          5 bar4                
group3               foo6                          1
```

We find the first value (`FIRST_VALUE`) for each row, ignore nulls (`ignore nulls`), for the current `record_group` "partition/group" (`partition by record_group`), for the whole "partition/group" (`rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following`) based on the order of record_level (`order by record_level`), and get rid of the duplicate rows with `DISTINCT`.